# How to increase the Sencha touch 2 app performance on Tablet(samsung) and Ipad

Tags: performance, sencha-touch-2

I have a requirement for tablet(Android) and ipad. For this am coding using sencha touch 2 wherein am not getting good performance after deploying on device using phonegap build. 
For instance-
1. If i tap on select field it takes some 5 seconds to display popup.
2. Also am creating side panel includes list, on tap of each list item am setting a separate view on detail panel. Here also its taking 5 seconds to set that view in detail panel(On samsung galaxy tablet its worst case while painting the screen).
Is there any way to increase the performance on tablet?? Please help me out in solving this performance issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about slow response to click events, you should look at what people at `yelp` did in their mobile website : http://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2013/01/mission-beyond-the-mobile-browser.html

Let me know if [this](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/blob/master/lib/fastclick.js) helps